# i want the parallax effect to include the h1 as well so it scrolls up without the image behind it, how can you do that?

Tags: html, css, position, parent-child, parallax

i want the name in the middle of the page to scroll up as i scroll down, i made the bottom div climb on top of the image with the fixed position but that somehow included the name and subtitle as well. i dont want that.

i have currently 2 container divs

and one div that got the texts inside it

here is the css code:

/thats the first fixed div with the image/

```
  #intro {
  display: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -99;
  background-image: url('images/la.jpeg');
  top: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
    }
```

/this second div is for the h1 and p 
its a child of the intro div with the image. /

```
 .infirst {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 250px 0 0 580px;
    }
```

/and last is the div climbing up on top of both of them /

```
.about-me {
 background-color: #000000;
 width: auto;
 height: 1000px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1000;
 margin-top: 100%;
     }
```

[picture of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJqB7.png)